# how can i clear the contents of the fileupload widget in a gwt application?

Tags: gwt

In a GWT application, I am using the fileupload widget and when I upload the first file then it shows progressbar corresponding file size and after completion of uploading, the progress bar hides and then I upload second file this time shows both progressbar of first file and second file. To solve this problem I refresh the page using `Window.Location.reload();` after uploading the first file, then it doesn't show the progressbar of the first file while uploading second file, it runs smooth. But there is no meaning of asynchronous of gwt. So how can I resolve this problem?

Thanks
rahul

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `fileUploadWidget.getElement().setPropertyString("value", "");` when `SubmitCompleteEvent` is called.

```
@UiHandler("uploadFileFormPanel")
void handleuploadFileFormPanelSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent e){
    uploadFile.getElement().setPropertyString("value", "");
    presenter.uploadCompleted(e);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Answered on the GWT forum: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/F3FIWQOBmqo/-lnJtAbV9xUJ

> The only way to clear an `<input type=file>` (or `FileUpload` widget in GWT) is to `reset()` the enclosing form (`FormPanel`). If that's not possible, then you'll have to replace the `FileUpload` with a newly created one (this is what I did years ago, works great)